# CQRS pattern, but Command function require some Query function

Tags: design-patterns, nestjs, cqrs

I got to separate the service into command and query. Some of the command methods require the methods from query. I initialized the query variable in the command's constructor. Here is the example in my nestjs app:

```
//command.ts
constructor(
    //...imports repos

    private salonServicesQuery: SalonServicesQuery //this one IMPORTED and be used later
  ) {
    //
  }

async updateService(serviceId: number, salonId: number, dto: UpdateServiceDto) {
    // do some cheking

    const service = await this.salonServicesQuery.getById(serviceId, salonId);// THIS one used to retrieve methods from the query class

    let category: any;
    if (dto.categoryId) {
      category = await this.categoryRepository.findOne({
        where: { id: dto.categoryId, salon: { id: salonId } },
      });

      if (!category) {
        throw new NotFoundException(
          `Category with ID '${dto.categoryId}' not found in salon '${salonId}'`
        );
      }
    }
   // continue doing logical things
}
```

My question is: am I doing right to separate them? Are there any ways/approachs that make more sense/better?

I imported query class in command class. I did not run the program bc I still have error with env but the vsc marked it all green and no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CQRS, you must know that the databases for read and write should be separated. And the **source of truth for validation is the write model**. So the usage of the read model in command handlers is not recommended.

If you need the same logic to get data in the write model (command handlers) just like the way it is defined in the query handlers, you should know that DRY doesn't apply here. You better duplicate your logic on both sides.

The fact is we think we must reuse the modules (codes, functions, classes) to comply with DRY in any circumstances. But all situations aren't fit to apply DRY. For example, we try to apply DRY and reuse our queries in the specification pattern. But all sharings and reusabilities bring coupling. So as long as the coupling doesn't cost too much for us, we go with DRY.

On the other hand, in CQRS you want to make the write and read model **independent**. CQRS is the way to make your architecture loosely coupled and by separating read and write concerns, it offers an opportunity to optimize and focus on each one independently. So the goal of CQRS is kind of the opposite of sharing the logic on both sides.

Here is a good [article](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/cqrs-vs-specification-pattern) by Vladimir Khorikov about CQRS and the specification pattern. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: am I doing right to separate them?

"It depends".

If `service` and `category` are two different objects that share the same information, then you probably are not making future comprehension and maintenance better than they would be if you just used a single object.

If the information is different, then it is probably fine; it's *common* that we need some information beyond what is provided to us as inputs to do useful work; accessing an unlocked read-only copy of reference data is a perfectly reasonable thing to when processing a command, and using some flavor of facade to hide the details of how that is done insulates the command handler from future changes to those implementation details.

A litmus test: consider the case where, concurrent with the updateService processing, the salon services data is being changed -- is that OK?  If the answer is yes, then you can mentally treat the `service` data as "just another input"

```
async updateService(serviceId: number, salonId: number, dto: UpdateServiceDto) {
    // do some cheking

    const service = await this.salonServicesQuery.getById(serviceId, salonId);// THIS one used to retrieve methods from the query class

    updateService(serviceId, salonId, dto, service)
}

async updateService(serviceId: number, salonId: number, dto: UpdateServiceDto, service: ???) {
    let category: any;
    if (dto.categoryId) {
      category = await this.categoryRepository.findOne({
        where: { id: dto.categoryId, salon: { id: salonId } },
      });

      if (!category) {
        throw new NotFoundException(
          `Category with ID '${dto.categoryId}' not found in salon '${salonId}'`
        );
      }
    }
   // continue doing logical things
}
```

But if there is some business critical invariant that must be preserved, then you probably want to arrange your code in such a way that the maintenance of the invariant is more readily apparent, rather than using idioms that look like external reference data.